# how to get dependency of my C# dll in ctypes library python?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, ctypes, .net-framework-version

I want to run C# dll with .net framework 4.7 in python app.
I use dllExport nuget for my method in dll because ctypes with this way access my method.
Sample:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        [DllExport("MyMethod", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static int MyMethod(int a,int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

In python:

```
def myFunction():
  Dllpath = os.path.join("dll folder directory")
  os.add_dll_directory(Dllpath + r"myDll.dll")
  # WinDll used just windows os, in Linux is different
  lib = WinDLL(Dllpath + r"myDll.dll")
  lib.MyMethod(12,17)
```

it is work.

but when I use other library (dll) in my dll I get this Error:

```
[WinError -532462766] Windows Error 0xe0434352
```

I guess this error was for problem in dependency of my dll.

how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put "DllExport" above all functions you call in all dependencies too.